# Return value in function callback is undefined when trying to refer to it directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, error-handling, callback

I'm sure the way I worded the question was pretty awful.  I need to explain what's going on.

I'm using the Jquery-file-upload package.  The uploading and all that is working great, but I'm trying to do some error handling.  I want to be specific with the errors so I'm trying to get the 'error' value that the file upload script returns.

When I attempt to upload an unsupported file, I see in the console this information as the response:

```
name
"300x300_068012f8ad836d2bc459b099065426c6.jpg"

size
29472

type
"image/jpeg"

error
"Filetype not allowed"
```

In my jquery/javascript code, I can successfully get `file.name`, `file.size`, or `file.type` but whenever I try `file.error` all I get is "undefined" in the console.

Here's the function I'm using:

```
function loadNotesUploader() {
    $('#edit_media_notes_input').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                console.log(file.name); // works
                console.log(file.error); // undefined
                // do stuff depending on result
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why I'm not able to get the specific error string... and I kinda need to.

Comment: Did you do `console.log(file);`?

Comment: Did you debug and see whether the property is present in file?

Comment: @Jack, yes I did.  I get `File { size=21056, type="image/jpeg", name="300x300_babel1.jpg", more...}` in the console, but it doesn't give me any extra helpful information.

Comment: @karthick, could you clarify what you mean by "present in the file" and what kind of debugging you mean specifically?

Comment: @vertigoelectric: File { size=21056, type="image/jpeg", name="300x300_babel1.jpg", more...} Did you see whether the property error is present in the File object? Debug using firebug or developer tools in firefox or Chrome respectively.

Comment: @karthick, oops.  I thought you said "the file".  Well here's the thing.  It says what I told you in the console output, and usually I can click on it to get more information, but when I do it doesn't give me any helpful information.  Here's a screenshot of what it gives me:  http://snaps.vertigofx.com/009/snap000012_2013-04-09_21.59.43.png.  It doesn't even show me the information that it provides in the initial console output.